# How to make a Google mashup, allowing multiple users to pinpoint multiple locations on a map?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-maps

I need some inputs on how to show a map (public to all) and allow any user (whose email I should be able to track) to click several points on the map and make appropriate markers (it should just be visible as a point, nothing special). Other users SHOULD see those points as well. I should be able to access data on the backend as to who selected what point.

Any code pointers?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this example in the google maps API [here](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/v2/overlays.html#Draggable_Markers) to get the basic feel of how to play with *markers*.

Basically I would bind a mouse click event handler to the gmap, then use this to create a new marker at that position and add it to the map using map.addOverlay(marker).

You will then need some sort of server side script that you can pass the marker information to via an ajax call.